# Webapp2 sessions are lost between requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I'm using webapp2_extras to set a session variable. If I print the variable after setting it the value is correct. The save_sessions call is also made. However, when I make the request again the variable isn't set.

Most of the code is taken from the [webapp2 documentation](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html):

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        try:
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        return self.session_store.get_session()

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        foo = self.session.get('foo')
        print foo
        self.session['foo'] = 'bar'
        foo = self.session.get('foo')
        print foo
        self.response.write(BaseHandler)

config = {}
config["webapp2_extras.sessions"] = {
    "secret_key": "key",
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True, config=config)
```

This always returns "None something" but I want it to return "something something" for the second request.

Comment: @MartinKapfhammer No, unfortunately.

Comment: try to invoke self.response.out.write after each time using the session class ... perhaps that's a coincidence, but it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a fairly old question but I just ran into the same problem and here is what solved it for me.

I altered the webapp2 config object to add in the auth param.

What used to be:

```
config = {}
config["webapp2_extras.sessions"] = {"secret_key": "key" }

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True, config=config)
```

Should now be:

```
config = {}
config["webapp2_extras.sessions"] = {"secret_key": "key" }
config["webapp2_extras.auth"] = {'session_backend': 'securecookie'}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True, config=config)
```

Comment: you don't have to define "webapp2_extras.auth" session backend if it's securecookie.... its the default behaviour

Comment: Correct, this doesn't fix anything for me and shouldn't fix anyone's issue since `'securecookie'` is the default value. If this really did fix you and the people who upvoted, there are some ghosts in the webapp2 backend...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my config I have this to set the location of the session store (for app engine the config is a bit different to the standard I understand)

```
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
      # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        return self.session_store.get_session(name='mc_session',
        factory=sessions_memcache.MemcacheSessionFactory)
```

Try that perhaps? Otherwise your code look OK to me, without actually running it.

You'll also need this import:

```
from webapp2_extras import sessions_memcache
```

[Webapp2 Memcache sessions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/sessions_memcache.html)

Comment: I leant about webapp2 sessions and GAE from here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html can you get the example code provide to behave as expected? EDIT: I expect you can, as it's the code you posted! MIght have some time later to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the datastore as the session backend, this probably has to do with eventual consistency. If you try to postpone the second request for a few seconds, and then attempt the request you will probably see the session data, and that proves it.

Switching to `securecookie` may help, though it didn't work for me for some reason... Still looking into it.

---

A big part of my problem was actually due to my ignorance of the cookie standards. It is explained in this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225984/persisting-webapp2-sessions-on-gae/25228652#25228652).

Comment: there's no eventual consistency in gets and auth tokens and sessiones are retrieved with gets.

Comment: @janscas I have to politely disagree. The main Guest Book example by Google shows you how if you try to get a list of guest book comments right after a write to the datastore, it will not return a recently written comment.

Comment: do you mean this example? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python/blob/part4-usingdatastore/guestbook.py

Comment: There is no such Guest book comments... but if you are meaning guest book greetings.. yes, they are retrieved using a query. There is no eventually consistency in Gets

Comment: @janscas What is Gets? you mean, get_by_id? That indeed is strongly consistent.

Comment: Yes i mean get by id. So.. If auth tokens and sessions are get using get by id... Then there is no posibility on having eventual consistency

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What fixed it for me was to set the backend to be different from the default (securecookie). setting it to memcache seemed to work for me.

```
    @webapp2.cached_property
        def session(self):
        return self.session_store.get_session(backend="memcache")
```

I also set this in the config under `.auth`. Not sure if this overwrites the `backend` parameter for `get_session` anyway...

```
config["webapp2_extras.auth"] = {'session_backend': 'memcache'}
```