# Persisting Webapp2 Sessions on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I am having trouble persisting my session variables in a webapp2 session store, while running on GAE. I have created a super simple app to reproduce the issue:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        session = self.session_store.get_session()

        previous_value = session.get("myvalue")
        self.response.write(previous_value)

    def get(self):

        session = self.session_store.get_session()

        previous_value = session.get("myvalue")
        self.response.write(previous_value)

        session["myvalue"] = "Hi! " + (previous_value if previous_value else "")

    # this is needed for webapp2 sessions to work
    def dispatch(self):

        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

        try:
            super(MainHandler, self).dispatch()

        finally:
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)
```

The premise here is that the `get` request sets a session variable while the `post` simply writes to the response object.

My understanding is that after performing the `get` request, the session persists `myvalue`. After that, if I perform a `post` request, then a `get` request again, `myvalue` should still be there, even though I didn't set it again in the `post` handler. Alas, that is not the case:

```
>>> cookies = None
>>> for i in range(10):
...     r = requests.get("http://localhost:11282/", cookies=cookies)
...     cookies = r.cookies
...     print r.text
... 
None
Hi! 
Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
>>> 
>>> cookies = None
>>> for i in range(10):
...     r = requests.get("http://localhost:11282/", cookies=cookies)
...     cookies = r.cookies
...     print r.text
...     r = requests.post("http://localhost:11282/", cookies=cookies)
...     cookies = r.cookies
...     print r.text
... 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi! 
None
Hi!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I am fairly new to web technologies and standards, I seem to have missed something:

```
def save_session(self, response):
    if self.session is None or not self.session.modified:
        return
```

This is the implementation of `SecureCookie`. Since the cookie is not saved to the response if it is not modified, I am guessing that per standard/protocol, the backend is not responsible for sending the cookie again, as it should already be on the client. It would be great to find a reference to this.

---

This proves it (switching to `requests.Session()`):

```
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> for i in range(5):
...     r = s.get("http://localhost:11282/")
...     print r.text
...     r = s.post("http://localhost:11282/")
...     print r.text
... 
None
POST
Hi! 
POST
Hi! Hi! 
POST
Hi! Hi! Hi! 
POST
Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! 
POST
>>>
```

Comment: Correct - once a "real" browser receives a cookie it will send it with every subsequent request to the same domain (subject to expiration time, if the cookie has one). Thus, the server doesn't need to resend the cookie if it is unchanged.

Comment: @SimonJ Thanks for confirming my doubts. I also found `requests.Session()` that acts more like a "real" browser.